# Worklight Development Server does not start

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am trying to follow the Getting Started section for Worklight on developerWorks. I have installed Worklight Studio 6.1 Consumer Edition (instead of Development Edition) into Eclipse 4.3.2. I did the basic creation of an app and tried to run it. However, the Worklight Development Server that was automatically created for me will not start. I deleted the app to see if I could get it to start but it still fails. The error message is:

```
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0005E: The application _MobileBrowserSimulator cannot start because the server is not configured to handle applications of type war.
```

That was the same error I was getting for the app I created. I can see no place in the server configuration to tell it whether or not it should handle WAR files. In fact, it will gladly allow me to add a Web Application based on a WAR file via the Server Configuration editor. The entire console for the Worklight Development Server is:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 10777
Launching worklight (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.0/wlp-1.0.3.20130524-0951) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.7.0_51-b13 (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server worklight has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server worklight is ready to run a smarter planet.
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0005E: The application _MobileBrowserSimulator cannot start because the server is not configured to handle applications of type war.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0036I: The server worklight stopped after 1 minutes, 0.848 seconds.
```

How do I tell the development server to handle WAR files? Or is something else going on here?

Comment: Make sure you are using **Eclipse Jave EE 4.3.1 ("Kepler" SR1)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was the Java JDK I was using to run Eclipse and not the version of Kepler. I was using the IBM Java 7 JDK to run Eclipse but had configured the Oracle Java 7 JDK for running any apps in Eclipse. I had been told to use the Oracle JDK but thought that was only for running the apps. Once I switched to running Eclipse using the Oracle JDK, my apps and the server started. So, Worklight Studio v6.1 seems to work fine with Eclipse Kepler SR2 as long as you use the Oracle JDK.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem , here's the steps I followed to fix it.
make sure the system is using jre 7, I uninstalled jdk 1.8 and jre 8.
make sure you run eclipse using jre 7. I'm running eclipse EE 4.4.0.
in eclipse go to>>windows>>preferences>> 
 - java>>installed JREs>>: Add JRE 7 dir then select it
 - java>>compiler: java compliance level 1.7

The most important step after doing what's stated above is to switch to a new workspace. File>> switch workspace>> Other: type the dir of the new workspace.

After eclipse start, just run the server.
If you import projects from the old workspace later, make sure you clean and build the project after moving it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work out of the box, since Worklight Studio itself generates .war files.

Make sure you are using Eclipse **Jave EE 4.3.1** ("Kepler" SR1)
Use it with a new workspace
And a fresh installation of Worklight