# Worklight Development server won't start

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-server

I am trying to start developing using IBM Worklight and am following the steps here: 
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/01_01_Setting_up_your_Worklight_development_environment.pdf

I have downloaded the following:

1. Eclipse Java EE 4.3.1 win 64-bit ("Kepler" SR1)
2. IBM Worklight 6.1 (From "Help > Eclipse Marketplace")

I am using Java JDK 7 win 64-bit

I have also set the text File encoding to UTF-8

When I attempt to start the Worklight Development Server I receive the following errors:

```
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0005E: The application Demo1 cannot start because the server is not configured to handle applications of type war.
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0005E: The application _MobileBrowserSimulator cannot start because the server is not configured to handle applications of type war.
```

Here is the entire console log:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 10777
Launching worklight (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.0/wlp-1.0.3.20130524-0951) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.7.0_60-b19 (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server worklight has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server worklight is ready to run a smarter planet.
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0005E: The application Demo1 cannot start because the server is not configured to handle applications of type war.
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0005E: The application _MobileBrowserSimulator cannot start because the server is not configured to handle applications of type war.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0036I: The server worklight stopped after 1 minutes, 0.170 seconds.
```

This same problem has been addressed here ([Worklight Development Server does not start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921815/worklight-development-server-does-not-start?newreg=83acebe7cc3a412aaa8160aa0e4f85ae)), however I have tried that user's solution of using Java JDK 7 and still see the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Installing Java in your machine is not enough; what do you have set-up in Eclipse > Preferences > Installed JREs?

Comment: Ok so I found that I accidentally had the jre set to the jdk path. I have now changed it so that jre 7 is set as the default. I have also added firewall rules to allow port 10080. Unfortunately the server still fails to start, but now with a different error:

    "Failed to deploy the application to Worklight server: please verify that the Worklight server is started and reachable.Connection to - 9.41.68.241:10080 failed. (Connection to http://9.41.68.241:10080 refused)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was an issue with the MobileBrowserSimulator Application within my Eclipse Workspace (Perhaps a file was corrupted). After recreating my Eclipse workspace the Worklight Server was able to start.

Answer (score 0):

Your second error might be caused because your machine has two different IPs. So if you are using "localhost" in your server, Worklight Studio will try to guess your IP and fail getting an incorrect one. I suggest you to go to Servers View, double click Worklight Development Server, and in the server editor, change the Host name from "localhost" to the specific IP you want to use.