# Worklight Server 6.2 Context not found

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

I am trying to install and configure Worklight application center on liberty profile.

I have installed the worklight 6.2 using the installation manager. Along the installation process i have installed the appcenter as well.

The installation was successful. But when i try to access the console it giving me "Context root not found".

Also I have checked the server.xml of the liberty server. It contains the appcenterconsole.war and the applicationcenter.war mapped.

Does anyone experience this problem as well?

Comment: Also i got an error in the log stating "The application appcenterconsole cannot start because the server is not configured to handle applications of type war"

Comment: Did you restart the Liberty Server after the installation ? If you did, an other possible explanation is that you have an other Liberty Server running on the same HTTP port...

Comment: For the error 'The application appcenterconsole cannot start because the server is not configured to handle applications of type war' -- which version of Liberty do you have and what features have you installed (you can see that with command <libertyInstallDir>/bin/productinfo featureInfo )

Comment: @Rajamanickam, we are waiting for a response from you.

Comment: Which version of JRE are you using to run Liberty? And what is the OS type and version?

Answer (score 0):

This might be the same problem as mentioned here: [Worklight Development Server does not start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921815/worklight-development-server-does-not-start)

Please make sure you use Oracle Java, not IBM Java!