# worklight-development-server-does-not-start timeout

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-server

Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 10777
Launching worklight (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.1/wlp-1.0.4.cl50120131011-1639) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.7.0_60-ea-b15 (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server worklight has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host):     `http://Lalit:10080/IBMJMXConnectorREST/`
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server worklight is ready to run a smarter planet.
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0005E: The application WorklightServices cannot start because the server is not configured to handle applications of type war.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0017I: Web application removed (default_host): `http://Lalit:10080/IBMJMXConnectorREST/`
[ERROR   ] CWWKZ0005E: The application WorklightConsole cannot start because the server is not configured to handle applications of type war.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0036I: The server worklight stopped after 3 minutes, 2.429 seconds.

Comment: I searched. but the resolution provided doesn't solved my problem. I also created fresh workspace.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Worklight Development Server does not start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921815/worklight-development-server-does-not-start)

Answer (score 1):

Same question: [Worklight Development Server does not start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921815/worklight-development-server-does-not-start)

Verify you have Oracle Java installed and that Eclipse is configured to use it in Preferences > Java > Installed JREs

This seems to solve the problem. See if it solves yours as well.

Also consider upgrading to the latest available 6.2.0.0 iFix, currently dated August 18th.
You can get it either from IBM Fix Central website or by updating your Worklight Studio installation from Eclipse marketplace.

Comment: Installed JRE is fine. But still unable to start the server within 180 seconds.
JRE:
java version "1.7.0_60-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-ea-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)

Comment: Open Worklight Development server wizard (by double clicking the worklight development server under servers view). In that wizard you can see Timeouts for start and stop operation of Worklight Server. Try to increase the timeout value.

Comment: Increasing the timeout value didn't helped. now it is saying unable to start withing 360 seconds.

Comment: It says multiple problems occurred:
Starting WL Development server
Stopping WL Development server.

Comment: If you are using Worklight 6.2, please verify in Eclipse > Help > About > Worklight that your build is from August 1st, which contains fixes in this department.

Comment: Yes, I am using Worklight 6.2 WorklightStudioPlugin Version 6.2.0.00-20140801-1709. I am facing issue in this build.

Comment: Worklight 6.2 WorklightStudioPlugin Version 6.2.0.00-20140812-1824 solved the issue.
Thanks